# From generic to specific type

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to extend a class and make it's dynamic type collapse into specific type (from `T` to `Person`).

I have created dummy classes for this example:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string){}
}

class Base<T> {
    reference?: T
    name: string

    constructor(name: string) {
        //  Assign properties from T to this
        this.name = name
    }

    static fromObject<T extends { name: string }>(object: T){
        const base = new Base(object.name)
        base.reference = object
        return base
    }
}

class Master<T> extends Base<T> {

    static fromBase<T>(base: Base<T>){
        const master = new Master(base.name)
        master.reference = base.reference
        return master
    }

    static fromObject<T extends { name: string }>(object: T){
        return Master.fromBase(Base.fromObject(object))
    }
}

class PersonMaster extends Master<Person>  {

    constructor(person: Person){
        super(person.name)
        this.reference = person
    }

    static fromBase(base: Base<Person>){
        return new PersonMaster(base)
    }
}
```

The compiler returns this error:

Class static side `typeof PersonMaster` incorrectly extends base class static side `typeof Master`. Types of property `fromBase` are incompatible. Type `(base: Base<Person>) => PersonMaster` is not assignable to type `<T>(base: Base<T>) => Master<{}>`. Types of parameters `base` and `base` are incompatible. Type `Base<T>` is not assignable to `Base<Person>`. Type `T` is not assignable to type `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `fromBase` in `Master` is generic:

```
static fromBase<T>(base: Base<T>)
```

This is *universal quantification*: it says that `fromBase` should work for all `T`. So when you try to specialise the argument to `Base<Person>` in `PersonMaster`, the type checker rightly complains that this implementation of `fromBase` doesn't work for all `T`s, just for `Person`. The type parameters of an overriding method have to match the type parameters of the declared method.

To put it another way, the `T` declared in `fromBase` is a totally different `T` than the one from the enclosing scope. It just happens to shadow the name. It might be easier to understand if the two type parameters had different names:

```
class Master<T> extends Base<T> {
    static fromBase<U>(base: Base<U>) { /* ... */ }
}
```

In this instance, I suspect you intended to use the (*rigid*) `T` from `Master`, not a fresh (*higher-rank*) `T`. Sadly, as you point out in your comment, you can't use a static method to do this because TypeScript doesn't support it. (I haven't been able to find any documentation as to why the language designers made this decision. I personally can't think of any good reasons, though I'm sure there is one.) So you have to move your method to an instance method on some other object:

```
interface MasterFactory<T> {
    fromBase(base: Base<T>): Master<T>
}
class PersonMasterFactory implements MasterFactory<Person> {
    fromBase(base: Base<Person>): Master<Person> { /* ... */ }
}
let personMasterFactory = new PersonMasterFactory();
```

With this design, calls which would have gone to `PersonMaster.fromBase` will go to `personMasterFactory.fromBase`.

Overriding a static method is a pretty strange thing to do in the first place. Method overriding is about dynamically dispatching calls based on the type of the receiver, but (conceptually, at least) a static method has no receiver. The clue's in the name: it doesn't make sense to dynamically dispatch a static method!

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that into account when next using that, but it will give me `Static members cannot reference class type parameters.` error if I don't specify `T` in function definition

Comment: I didn't know that about static members. Seems like an oversight on the part of the TypeScript designers, though I'm sure there is a good reason for it. Anyway, I think you have a design issue: overriding static members is quite a strange thing to do. Overriding is an inherently dynamic behaviour, so if something needs to be overridden you should probably make it an instance property - in other words, extract a `MasterFactory` class

Comment: Should I make an issue on typescript GitHub? Why is overriding static methods strange, why use a factory instead? And edit your answer, as it unfortunately isn't correct.